# Getting an "COMPLEX DATA BINDING ACCEPTS DATA SOURCE AS ILIST" error when i try to populate my data grid in windows form using MS ACCESS

Tags: c#, datagrid, ms-access-2010

I am using access database. I have made the connection and data adapter as global variables.
On loading the form, my combo box is populated with all student ids. I am trying to fill my data grid with all the records of the student whose id I have selected in combo box. However, it is giving me the above mentioned error. I am relatively new and did check some documentation but I could not understand it.

```
namespace P1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =d:\DDBS.mdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Student", @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =d:\DDBS.mdb");   
        DataSet d1 = new DataSet("Student");

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            adap.Fill(d1, "Student");
            con.Open();
            int x = d1.Tables["Student"].Rows.Count - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(d1.Tables["Student"].Rows[i]["sid"]);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            OleDbCommand ada = new OleDbCommand( "SELECT  * FROM Student where sid= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'", con);
            ada.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataGrid1.DataSource = ada;
            MessageBox.Show("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the data adapter as your datasource directly but you need to populate i.e. a List/datatable and then assign it. The easiest way here would be:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable students = new DataTable();
da.Fill(students );
dataGrid1.DataSource = students ;
```

Comment: Oh, so i was first supposed to make a datatable and populate it with the adapter. Thanks